# Trim/clear new line character from batch script at Windows7 with gvim

Tags: vimscript, text-generation, command-line-window

I want to put timestamp using <kbd>Leader</kbd><kbd>t</kbd><kbd>s</kbd> (`\ts`)

I am using the following script `timestamp.bat`(Windows 7):

```
@echo off
cls
echo|set /p=%date:~0,4%-%date:~5,2%-%date:~8,2% %time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%
```

and the result should be something like that:

```
Lorem ipsum.. 2018-02-25 21:43 lorem ipsum..
```

Unfortunately, when I am in the correct position to put the timestamp, insertion go to one line under. I think it is due to the `<cr>` character at the begining of output.

How to trim  character from output if I have such a command:

```
nnoremap <leader>ts :r! timestamp.bat<CR>
```

or

```
 nnoremap <leader>ts :put =strftime(\"%c\")
```

Is there other solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you try: `:nnoremap <leader>ts A<C-R>=strftime('%c')<cr><esc>` ?

Comment: It works a little better, but it should put timestamp between text. Right now it adds text at the end of the line.

Comment: Use `a` then instead of `A`

Comment: Yes, this is exacly what I need `:nnoremap <leader>ts a<C-R>=strftime('%c')<cr><esc>`